# Sorting by a field of the "keyword" type, taking into account the values of the numbers contained in the field string

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to find a solution to sort the search result in elasticsearch by a field of type "keyword", the value of which can contain a string with a number at the same time. Since the "keyword" type is not analyzed, as a result of the search, the values 7, 5, 3 will be returned before the values 17, 15, 13 when sorting the "desc" type, which does not meet the expectation.
If you know how to configure the index and mapping, I would appreciate a hint.
First of all, I want to find a solution at the index settings level, in its absence, solve the problem at the query level in spring data elasticsearch. I don't want to think about sorting the result after the result is issued yet, because this will reduce the speed.

I applied the index setting below, expecting the result from "filter_pattern_replace", but this option does not work at all.

```
 "settings":{
      "analysis":{
           "filter": {
                "filter_pattern_replace": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": "\\d+",
                    "replacement": "NUMBER_TOKEN" 
                }  
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{
            "my_analyzer":{ 
                "type":"custom",
                "tokenizer":"my_tokenizer",
                "filter":[
                  "filter_pattern_replace",
                  "lowercase"
                ]
            }
         },
        "tokenizer":{ 
            "my_tokenizer": {
                "type":"edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 20,
                "token_chars": [
                    "letter",
                    "digit"
                ]
            }
        }
      }
   },
```

Comment: if your fields contain numbers, why do you store it a string and not as numeric type?

Comment: "...the value of which can contain a **string** with a number at the same time..." I think probably like `value 1`, `value 17`, etc

Comment: Yes, the field contains the value of a string and a number at the same time, for example, "The Godfather", "The Godfather 2" or "The next episode of the soap opera 123"

Comment: It look like I need to find this implementation in spring data elasticsearch:
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {} "match_all": {} },
      "boost": "5",
      "random_score": {}, 
      "boost_mode":  "sum"
    }
  }

Comment: You can pass any query that the native Elasticsearch client offers by using a NativeQuery in Spring Data Elasticsearch